# Youtube : Remove only "Watch later" & "Share" icon button on video

Tags: youtube

I have video Playlist gallery with embed code. I want to embed that in my private portal and that privacy can maintain by making video **"UNLISTED"** so that video doesn't show up in YouTube search as well as channels. I hope by making this way I can protect privacy of my videos or if any other way please suggest me.

Second thing I want to remove icon button "Watch later" & "Share" icon button on video. How we can make this if possible with the embed code. I can do this by **"showinfo=0"**. But by doing this it will remove the Title information of video. and wanted to keep that video title information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use flash version of YouTube player and disable external links property.